# Write to host file on Android Rooted Device

Tags: android

We have previously been using an emulator to run some of our tests on but now would like to use an actual Android device instead.

Part of our process is to make edits to the phones hosts file so we can send data to a different endpoint. To do this on an emulator we would launch like so with writeable access

```
emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_27 -noaudio -writable-system -no-snapshot-load -qemu &
```

and then run a shell script

```
sh hosts_override.sh


#!/bin/bash

external_ip="${EXTERNAL_HOST:-10.0.2.2}"

echo "Using external IP address $external_ip"

adb root
adb pull /system/etc/hosts /tmp/hosts
echo "$external_ip endpoint-1" >> /tmp/hosts
echo "$external_ip endpoint-2" >> /tmp/hosts
echo "$external_ip endpoint-3" >> /tmp/hosts
adb remount
adb push /tmp/hosts /system/etc
```

The problem we face at the moment is there seems to be no access to the phone (even though the phone has been rooted)

```
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
```

I can browse the files on the phone and see the hosts file

```
adb -s HT829GZ52000 shell
```

How do we get access so that we can write to the phone?

Comment: You would need to root the device. A simpler solution might be to connect the devices to a different WiFi access point, one where you can override the DNS resolution at the access point itself.

Comment: Thanks, device is already rooted. the goal here is to automate a process and part of that is writing to the hosts file, appreciate any further insight you may have

Comment: As @CommonsWare mentioned, wouldn't it be easier to create a DNS entry to point to wherever you need the phone's data to go? I imagine that the hosts file is locked down for a reason even on rooted phones i.e. to prevent malicious redirection.

Comment: apologies for the initial lack of understanding, treading in unfamiliar territory.  How would i go about that in my scenario ? I have come across this http://xslab.com/2013/08/how-to-change-dns-settings-on-android/, i guess the point you guys are making is that if i change the DNS settings then i would not need to have a step where i update any host files ? not 100% getting this at this stage sorry, appreciate your help

Comment: @Richlewis Brief comment-sized explanation: Let's say you have a network with a [DNS server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) set up on it at `192.168.1.2`, and all devices on that network are configured to use that DNS server. On that DNS server you have `mysite.com` configured to go to IP address `1.2.3.4`, any queries for `mysite.com` from devices on that network will go to `1.2.3.4` instead of its usual IP address. Works the same as editing the hosts file, without the need to compromise a device.

Comment: ok i can understand that and see how it works, im now just unclear on how i do this on the device ? apologies if this seems stupid, i have never done it before and dont want to break it :-)

Comment: @Richlewis If you have a DHCP server on the same network (your router should be able to do this), you can set the default DNS server for all devices via the DHCP settings. If you're setting this up via the device, go to `settings > wi-fi > (long-click your network SSID) > Modify Network > Advanced Options > IP Settings - Static > DNS 1 & DNS 2`